# My atom editor is not responding when i open new project file. But it works fine in safe mode

Tags: freeze, crash, kali-linux, atom-editor

I installed `atom-beta` some weeks ago. But from yesterday it freezes when I open a new project folder. I am using Kali Linux OS.

Today I installed stable Atom editor but getting same problem.

I think it's some package error, But I can't find it. I have upgraded it but nothing happens.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I solved this..

> #### I just uninstall `atom-beta` and remove the folder `.atom` and I install it again.

### My problem is gone..